# Rails form datepicker

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, datepicker, materialize

In a checkout I'm prompting a user to confirm his address and `required_date` to receive the part. The form is shown for the `@auction` attributes that are needed to be confirmed. All of the address lines are already populated. But the date field is cleared, I want the date field to be populated with the date that was already chosen(`@auction.required_date`), so that the user doesn't have to re-pick the date if the `required_date` has not changed.

Here's the form

```
.form-container
  %p#alert= alert
  = form_for(@auction, html: { class: "inline-form" }, remote: true ) do |f|
    - if @auction.errors.any?
      #error_explanation
        %h2
          = pluralize(@auction.errors.count, "error")
          prohibited this auction from being saved:
        %ul
          - @auction.errors.full_messages.each do |message|
            %li= message
    .field.form-group
      = f.text_field :destination_address, class: "form-control", placeholder: "Destination Street Address"
    .field.form-group
      = f.text_field :destination_city, class: "form-control", placeholder: "Destination City"
    .field.form-group
      = f.text_field :destination_state, class: "form-control", placeholder: "Destination State/Region"
    .field.form-group
      = f.text_field :destination_zip, class: "form-control", placeholder: "Destination Zip Code"
    .field.form-group
      = f.text_field :destination_country, class: "form-control", placeholder: "Destination Country"
    .field
      = f.date_field :required_date, class: "form-control datepicker", placeholder: "Required Delivery Date"
    %br/
    .actions.submit_button
      = f.submit 'Submit', class: "btn custom-btn"
    %br/


:javascript
  $('.datepicker').pickadate({
    selectMonths: true
  });
```

Comment: Just upoloaded it

Comment: Can you post a sample date value from your db. Also can you post the rendered HTML component for that date field (you can get this from the source code in any browser)

Answer (score 1):

I believe you can just do this:

`= f.date_field :required_date, class: "form-control datepicker", placeholder: "Required Delivery Date", value: @auction.required_date`

and it should populate the date field.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you have to add value in right format using strftime, for example:

```
value: @auction.required_date.strftime('%m/%d/%Y')
```